# problem building my map using SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to build my environment map using SLAM from this [Building a map with SLAM](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM)turtorial using my icreate base + kinect and yesterday at after many trials i got this picture and got (my_map.pgm & my_map.yaml) :-
[image]

and when i closed and tried to build another one from the beginning i didn't get any map i've tried many times but without any new results i always get this empty view on rviz :-
[image]

without building my map on rviz ..so is there any tips about what may went wrong with me ?...thanks in advance

i have added a video of my work :-

this video is from my workstation :-
[Workstation Rviz interface](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN4vMo0SQVY)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55614/problem-building-my-map-using-slam/) by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say you forget to run some node in your second try. But it's impossible to diagnose from a far what that might have been... I'd have a look at the output of the mapping node and check if there is data flowing on all the topics it subscribed to.

Driving around a bit also is a good idea, because the map usually only get's updated, if it changes and most mapping algorithms won't update the map without robot movement... depending on the launch order the first map can sometimes get missing, even though the topic is latched. Try to drive a few meters in one direction, if that happens.

---

Originally posted by [Achim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1188/achim/) with karma: 390 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-20**:
i have edited the question and added a video from my workstation ... if you have any comments sir ..thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As evident from one of the rviz screen shots in ur question the camera frame id is giving error because probably its not defined properly. For mapping first try to get laser scan correctly. Since ur using kinect, i am hoping ur using pointcloud_to_laserscan package for creating fake laser from pointcloud. Try getting laser scans, if ur able to see laserscan properly in rviz then that means ur tf tree is perfect. Once that works fine you can use turtlebot_navigation package to create map. Ideally tf should be like this world->map->odom->base_link->laser.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-19**:
no i didn't use ointcloud_to_laserscan package at the first picture or second picture ...  so can you give me any tip about how to use this package ?

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-02-19**:
Download pointcloud_to_laserscan package for convering your pointcloud that you get from kinect into fake laser and then use the scan published by that package for gmapping. You can also go though this link for further details http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-20**:
thank you very much ..i'll try it and write down the feedback here to help the others with the same problem

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2013-02-20**:
i have edited the question and added a video from my workstation ... if you have any comments sir ..thank you ^_^